# Get all fields in a scala form

Tags: scala, playframework

I make a form in scala with Play 2 framework, and I've a problem to get all fields : 
Before I tested with only 2 fields, so it works :

```
def subscription = Action {
  implicit request =>
  signForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest,
    {        
      case (username, password) =>

        User.create(User(username, password))
        Ok(views.html.index(userForm, "visible", "User created."))
    }
  )
}
```

But when I want to have more than 2 fields, it doesn't work :

```
def subscription = Action {
  implicit request =>
  signForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest,
    {        
      case (username, password, firstname, lastname, company) =>

        User.create(User(username, password, firstname, lastname, company))
        Ok(views.html.index(userForm, "visible", "User created."))
    }
  )
}
```

It show me : constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) required: (String, String)

I understand that case() cannot have more than two parameters, but how I can get the other fields in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the problem is in the error message. Your form `signForm` is defined as a (String, String) and you need to extend it to include the additional fields. If you include the code for your form, a more detailed answer can be given.

Comment: yes, my definition of my Form wasn't good, it works now thanks !